# Is there a method to import markdown into a trac wiki instance?

Tags: documentation, markdown, wiki, trac

I use a trac wiki all the time to maintain some documentation.  I've looked at solutions like doxygen (we already comment our code this way, Drupal) but we also have staff that don't really touch code.

For them, and for myself, I'd love to be able to simply maintain a markdown document(s) and periodically import that into our trac instance.

Given that trac already uses markdown, I was wondering if there were any plugins that could parse a directory of markdown documents and automagically push em into the trac wiki?

Does this make any sense? Does this type of plugin exist?

Answer (score 3):

It could be scripted. You could run the script in the post-commit hook of a version control system, or from a cron job that grabbed documents from a service such as DropBox.  Documents can be added to the Trac wiki using the [TracAdmin command line tool](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracAdmin).  There's also the [XmlRpcPlugin](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/XmlRpcPlugin) in case that you need to publish the document from another host. However, Trac does not use markdown (yet). It uses a [syntax](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/WikiFormatting) loosely based on MoinMoin, and also a [WikiCreole](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/WikiCreole) syntax. It also supports ReST if docutils is installed.

Comment: Ah, excellent answer.  I didn't know about the TracAdmin tool.  Sometimes the simplest solutions are the best.